# Getting error When client closes the connection

Tags: python, client-server

```
import socket
tcpsocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

tcpsocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET , socket.SO_REUSEADDR , 1)
tcpsocket.bind(('0.0.0.0',8000))
tcpsocket.listen(2)
print "Server Started "
(client,(ip,port))=tcpsocket.accept()


print "Client connected " + ip 

client.send("Welcome to 8000 \n Type in something and see it echoed back")

data="dummy"

while True:
    data=client.recv(3096)
    if data is None :
       break
    print "Client Typed in " + data + "\n" 
    client.send(data)

print "Closing Conneection"    
client.close()

print "Shutting down server"   
tcpsocket.close()
```

When i close the client i get the following error..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PYTHON/Client-Server.py", line 18, in <module>
    data=client.recv(3096)
error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

It is pointing to the line

```
data=client.recv(3096)
```

How do i break a connection smoothly.

Comment: You need to check the return value of the `recv` call. I think it returns `None` when the other end has closed the connection. Attempting to send or receive on the socket after the other end has closed the connection will cause an error.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Have included the statement , but still gives an error when disconecting

Comment: If you read e.g [this Windows socket error reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you will see that the error might be because the remove program crashed or something, or otherwise didn't close its connection in a nice way. The only way to detect it is to catch the exception.

Comment: How does the client close the connection? Do you have the relevant source code for the client?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I added try/except bloc. That solved my problem. Thanks :)

Comment: @Robᵩ i was using netcat utility to connect to the ip address with the port, netcat was my client.